# Given a group $G$, does there exist a domain $D$ with $G$ as its ideal class group?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have only recently encountered algebraic number theory and was wondering if this is the case. If the answer to the question is yes, then can we explicitly construct the domain $D$ ?

Comment: $G$ must be abelian...

Comment: I know this is a repeat... Yes: [here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/finite-abelian-groups-as-class-groups) for finite abelian groups.

Comment: @Fortuon: It should be obvious from the definition of ideal class group that it is abelian. If this is not obvious, perhaps you should first learn what the ideal class group is!

Comment: @ZhenLin: My apologies for the notation abuse. I have corrected it.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. The ideal class group is commutative because multiplication is commutative in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and any reasonable definition of fractional ideal classes of an integral domain $D$ will make use of multiplication in $D$. Your question doesn't make sense for general non-commutative domains because there isn't even a reasonable definition of fraction field in that case.

Comment: The paper by Claborn cited in @Mariano's answer does not seem to be restricted to *finite* groups.

Comment: If you feel that @Mariano has answered your question fully then just accept his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Claborn, Luther (1966), "Every abelian group is a class group", Pacific J. Math. 18: 219–222. You can get it [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-18/issue-2/Every-abelian-group-is-a-class-group/pjm/1102994263.full)

Comment: Our dear Pete Clark has a recent result on this subject. You should find it in his webpage.

Comment: Have you looked?