# Inverse Galois theory and Hilbert class field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I am not sure if the following questions have an answer.

> **(Question 1)** Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group. Is it possible to find an unramified Abelian extension $L/K$ such that
>
> $$G \cong \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$$
>
> Can we drop the condition of $G$ being Abelian?

--

> **(Question 2)** Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group. Is it possible to find an extensions $L/K$ such that
>
> $$G \cong \mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \cong CL(K)$$
>
> where $L$ is the Hilbert Class Field of $K$ and the last isomorphism follows from Artin reciprocity. This would give us a method to construct maximal unramified Abelian extensions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to the second question is surely unknown, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/finite-abelian-groups-as-class-groups

Comment: If we COULD drop the condition of being abelian in Q1 surely the inverse galois problem would be solved?

Comment: @fretty: the inverse galois problem asks for extensions over the rationals (i.e. $K=\mathbb{Q}$). In my question this is not a requirement.

Comment: Well it is natural to ask for the groups which occur as extensions of an arbitrary number field. As far as I know this question is unsolved.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is yes. Construct an extension $K/F$ with given Galois group and lift it to an extension $KL/FL$ where $L$ and $K$ are disjoint and $L$ is chosen in such a way that it kills the ramification in $K/F$. This result was first proved by Arnold Scholz, then by Emil Artin in a private communication to Helmut Hasse (see their [correspondence](http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9783034807142)), and finally it was rediscovered by Ali Froehlich.

As for the second question, Ozaki has recently shown (Construction of maximal unramified p-extensions with prescribed Galois groups, Invent. Math. 183 )2011),
649-680) that every finite $p$-group is the Galois group of the $p$-class field 
tower of a suitable number field.