# How to construct rings with a given class number?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Hi I was learning about class number and I was wondering if it is known how to construct rings for any specific class number.

Comment: Mark Watkins has tabulated all rings of integers of imaginary quadratic number fields with class number $h=1,\ldots,100$. So this solves your question "in practice" for small $h$. However, in general it is not known whether or not all finite abelian groups appear as class groups of number fields (i.e., ring of integers) - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/finite-abelian-groups-as-class-groups).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for every finite abelian group one can construct a Dedekind domain with class group isomorphic to that group. This is a result from the 1960s due to Claborn.

For details see for example:

Pete L. Clark: [Elliptic Dedekind domains revisited.](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/ellipticded.pdf) Enseignement Math. 55 (2009), 213-225.

Comment: There is a more recent result of Ozaki (published around 2010 ?) showing that any p-group can be realized as the class group of a number field.

Comment: Yes, I thought if I should discuss the number field case, but decided against it. See [this answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/101027) where I first learned about the result you mentioned.

Comment: By the way, Claborn's result is for *all* commutative groups, not just finite ones.  I suspect that one can show that every finite commutative goup is the ideal class group of some **S-integer ring** in a number field.  This is equivalent to: every finite commutative group is the quotient of a class group of some number field and also to: for any positive integers n and k, the class group of some number field has at least k elements of order n.  I think that should be a known result, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark in retrospect I am not sure why I wrote the finite there. Indeed, it is known that every finite abelian group is the quotient of the class group of a number field (even a cyclic one).

Comment: @quid: I'm glad to hear that....can you give me a reference? I googled a bit after my last comment and didn't come up with anything.  (Do you maybe mean "cyclotomic" instead of cyclic?)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Washington, Intro. to Cyc. Fields. chapter 3, towards the end. (Yes.)

Comment: Thanks very much.  (For a lecture I gave in a graduate course less than a year ago, I used material from the same page of Washington's book.  I'm kind of annoyed that I somehow ignored this nice result.)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow me to interpret your question for more general rings than Dedekind rings, then there are also the following examples.
Let $C\subseteq \mathbf P^2$ be a nonsingular curve of degree $h$, Then the complement $\mathbf P^2\setminus C$ is an affine algebraic variety whose coordinate ring has class group $\mathbf Z/h$.